# new to profiling allocations in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, profiling, instruments

I'm doing a screenshot of the allocations in my project. I've simulated a memory warning at 50 seconds, but the allocations never go back down. Maybe I don't understand this one correctly?

[image: screenshot of profile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that NONE of my big objects (UIViews / Controllers) were ever being released. After diving in I'm seeing some up and down like I should be.

Answer (score 1):

I think the graph is displaying the overall bytes, ie all the memory consumed by the application during her running time